# Python3 "@typing.overload" and parameters

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt5, overloading

I do not know how to proceed to define a derived class which has an overloaded `__init__()` constructor with different numbers or parameters.

The class is from Qt5, and I am using PyQt5 (though I don't think this matters in itself).  In `QtGui.pyi` I see:

```
class QStandardItemModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, parent: typing.Optional[QtCore.QObject] = ...) -> None: ...
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, rows: int, columns: int, parent: typing.Optional[QtCore.QObject] = ...) -> None: ...
```

My starting attempt is:

```
class DBStandardItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, parent: typing.Optional[QtCore.QObject] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, rows: int, columns: int, parent: typing.Optional[QtCore.QObject] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(rows, columns, parent)
```

However, in PyCharm the second `__init__` warns me:

```
A series of @overload-decorated methods should always be followed by an implementation that is not @overload-ed
```

1. What code should I be writing for the final `__init__` definition, given that you can see the overloads have different numbers of parameters?
2. PyCharm does not seem to complain about the definitions from `QtGui.pyi` which do not offer an extra non-overloaded definition, yet it seems to in my code.
3. I have put the `super().__init__()`s into each of my overloads as without that PyCharm complains `Call to __init__ of super class is missed`, I don't know if that is right/required.

Comment: Please read [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) part of PEP 484 about stub files and `typing.overload` usage in stub files and regular Python files.

Comment: Thank you, from PEP 484 I now understand why `QtGui.pyi` has only the `@overload`s [my point #2].  I also see that it does not matter what the bodies of the `overload`s are, since they do not get called, so the PyCharm warning about `__init__` missing is probably spurious [my point #3].
That still leaves me with #1: how do actually write the single implementation definition in this case, given the different number of parameters?  I can only think of having to use: `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` --- is that the right approach?